# How do i check for duplicate data in Sqlite Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

> I have this code that gets emails from the input field in tkinter python and stores it in the database, I later on plan to use this data to send emails automatically to all emails in the database. But the only problem is that if i input the same email twice it saves them in the database with no errors and that will cause to send duplicate information to the email. So can anyone advice on what approach i should take?

```
def submit():
# Creates the connection from the database.py
conn = sqlite3.connect("email.db")
c = conn.cursor()

# Insert into the database table
c.execute(
    "INSERT INTO email VALUES (:email_address)", {"email_address": user_email.get()}
)

conn.commit()
conn.close()

# Clear The Text Boxes
user_email.delete(0, END)
```

> This is how i retrieve the information from the database if its any useful

```
def emailGet():
# Creates the connection from the database.py
conn = sqlite3.connect("email.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM email")
records = c.fetchall()
print("This is all the emails in the database : " + str(records))
global get_records
global new_record
get_records = ""

for i in records:
    get_records += str(i[0] + ",")
    #print(get_records)
    new_record = get_records[:-1]
    print(new_record)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: If you have the option, you could set the email column to be `unique` -now you just have to handle the insert failures as trying insert duplicates will fail. If setting email to unique is not an option, then sqlite should have `select distinct ...` that you can use in your `select *, oid from email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `SELECT` statement to check if the email you fetch from the entry is in the database.
Something like this:

```
def checkEmailExistance():
    email_exists = False
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM email WHERE <email adresses column> = :email_adress'
    {"email_address": user_email.get()})

    # Previous line selects a row of your database only if the column that contains
    # the email adress in said row has the same adress as the one from the entry

    if c.fetchone() # which is the same as saying "if c.fetchone retrieved something in it"
        email_exists = True 
    else:
        email_exists = False
    return email_exists
```

Also, instead of using the `email_exists` variable you could just return True or False to shorten the code, I wrote it that way for readability.

**Edit** This has nothing to do with your questions but while working with databases i found that is extremely usefull to add an "value_id" column at the beggining of every table which loads and updates automatically, you never know when you're going to need it!

Hope this helps